# Arranging a range of rows in a data frame to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file where the data is arranged in rows. I have to rearrange the data in a way that from row 92 'Voltage:' 'Current:'and the values below it is moved to a separate column. [image]

The problem I am facing is that the IVC file contains a lot of data like this. The 'Voltage:' 'Current:' values ends[image: Second values] at  row 7117 and the second set of values 'Voltage 2',Current2 starts and it need to be be arranged as a seperate columns.

[image: 3rd image]

I would like get this problem solved by writing a loop which will go throw the starting row(92) till the end and convert the values into separate columns lie(Volage, Current, Voltage1, Current etc) till the last row.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to solve this problem.

file sample [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Affc-mzvey9C_BnDzHctrGdNSYMh8-0a/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @Trenton McKinney Could you please help me with this problem.

Comment: Should the additional columns start at row zero or just shift over leaving the first column blank?  Please provide some sample CSV data for testing.

Comment: @Mike67 yes, the new columns should start from row zero. I have added the link in the question for the test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this data, split the data while reading the ivc file and store all the data in lists. After reading the full file, merge the lists into a dataframe.

Note that the lists had different lengths so I filled in -1 to fill the difference.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {} # all column data

with open('MCIND_2021_0074_0001.ivc') as f:
   for ln in f.readlines():
      ln = ln.strip()  # trim whitespace
      # check for header row
      if ln.startswith('Volt') or \
      ln.startswith('Ref ') or \
      ln.startswith('Raw ') or \
      ln.startswith('WPVS '): # start new lists
         hdr=[h.strip() for h in ln.split(':')[:2]] # store headers
         d[hdr[0]], d[hdr[1]] = [], []  # start new list
      elif d != {} and ln != '':  # check if data row
         data = ln.split()   # split data
         d[hdr[0]].append(data[0])  # add to data lists
         d[hdr[1]].append(data[1])

# not all columns have same length, find max length
mxlen = 0
for k in d: 
   print(k, len(d[k]))
   if len(d[k]) > mxlen: 
       mxlen = len(d[k])
       
print('Max column length',mxlen)

# fill in -1 to make columns same length
for k in d: 
   d[k].extend([-1]*(mxlen-len(d[k])))

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('volt.csv', index=False)
```

Output

```
Voltage 3512
Current 3512
Ref Cell 3512
Lamp I 3512
Voltage2 4800
Current2 4800
Ref Cell2 4800
Lamp I2 4800
Voltage3 4800
Current3 4800
Ref Cell3 4800
Lamp I3 4800
Raw Voltage 3512
Raw Current 3512
WPVS Voltage 3512
WPVS Current 3512

Max column length 4800

  Voltage    Current   Ref Cell     Lamp I   Voltage2   Current2  ...  Ref Cell3    Lamp I3 Raw Voltage Raw Current WPVS Voltage WPVS Current
-1.134066  8.9474330  82.756460  20.229190  -1.146221  8.9530360  ...  0.0000000  0.0000000   -1.132690   8.9343730    1.5327920    0.1541779
-1.137213  8.9462380  82.745280  20.229960  -1.146221  8.9526370  ...  0.0000000  0.0000000   -1.135833   8.9331800    1.5309610    0.1539949
-1.140361  8.9458380  82.745280  20.229190  -1.139925  8.9522350  ...  0.0000000  0.0000000   -1.138977   8.9327820    1.5292060    0.1538195
-1.137212  8.9454400  82.745280  20.229190  -1.139925  8.9522350  ...  0.0000000  0.0000000   -1.135832   8.9323840    1.5276040    0.1536593
-1.137211  8.9450400  82.745280  20.229960  -1.133631  8.9522330  ...  0.0000000  0.0000000   -1.135831   8.9319840    1.5262310    0.1535220
```

Comment: I created another data frame named Power(Current*Voltage). I would like to get the values of Current and Voltage corresponding to the maximum value of Power. Could you help me with that?

Comment: That will require another algorithm. Please post another question with whatever code you have. Thanks.